# Change Requests Billing

Tags: freelancing, maintenance, change

I have a website developed for my client, and he's currently on an annual maintenance billing for the same post development pushed to production, that he'd paid me for the development charges separately, and then the maintenance billing, which i generate every month.

Now he comes up with new change request, which was not part of the development which I had done. So just wanted to know, should I charge him for each change request (per hour basis), or probably it should come under the maintenance fees he has paid me.

I am new to freelancing and this is my first project, so I am not aware of the billing things. Please let me know what would be the ideal way of handling change requests and maintenance.

Comment: It depends on what your maintenance contract covers. If only software defects are covered, it's obvious that new requirements are not included. If your contract covers something like a number of hours working for the customer, he may decide that when there are no bugs to fix you might just as well add functionality.

Comment: I think it's part of owning a business to make that call. My advice is to be transparent and predictable, if you are going to charge him, send a quote indicating the scope of work and cost, if it's going to be free, also agree on the scope of work beforehand.

Comment: Per the contract, i had only mentioned maintenance charges, does that mean to be assumed the new change request would also be included?